# Add variable amount of columns to a table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am doing a project where I am not sure how many columns I will need.

For example, one column I might have is,

```
(1, xyz, c1, c2, c3, c4)
```

and the other might have

```
(2, xyz, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6)
```

I am not sure what to do, thanks!

Comment: You'll need to create a table having all possible columns (or execute `ALTER TABLE` whenever a new column appears) and then just store the values you have - as long as those variable columns allow for null entries there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: How do you make it allow null entries?

Comment: From the official [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) docs: _The default value of each column is NULL._ You don't need to change anything if you're using default columns - you'll only have to alter columns that have `NOT NULL` constrains that you want to keep empty.